# Connection Error for Node.js app on Heroku after Redis upgrade

Tags: heroku, redis, heroku-redis

We have an app created with node.js which is Hosted on Heroku.

After the upgrade of Redis from a free plan to paid plan, our app is not connecting.

As per the suggestion from Heroku support team, we added the below code on our app, but there is no luck

```
const client = redis.createClient({
  url: process.env.REDIS_URL,
  socket: {
    tls: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
```

We are getting the below errors on the logs

[image]

Is there any suggestions which can be given over here?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am getting the same error, so it will be helpful if you share your solution.